# How to use powershell to store sql query in variable and output in grid view box?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I recently started a new job and have never had to call sql queries within Powershell before. Any assistance would be appreciated. I know I am making newbie mistakes, but arrays are not my strong suit.

I am looking for the query stored in the $customer variable to pull a list of database names and display it in an out-gridview box. The person should be able to select the database they wish to work with and the database name should be stored in a variable as text to use in the subsequent test-path commands.

Right now when I run the command, the output I see is as shown. The $customer variable should show the customers name from the sql query, not System.Data.DataRow

Script so far:

```
    <#
.SYNOPSIS
   A script for migrating a portal from EC2/appn (N Virginia us-east-1) to a VPC cell.
.DESCRIPTION
   This script is currently written in local scope. Run while logged into Pacejet RDP.
.PARAMETER customer
   The name of the customer database to be migrated.
.EXAMPLE
   MigratePortal.ps1 -customer Decatur
#>
#Declare command line switches
Param
(
[string]$customer
)
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

 #Establish Pacejet paths in variables - Update as needed.
$plugins = "\\dbn\SharedApp\WebServices\PacejetPreprocessWS\PluginLibraries\$customer\"
$occonfig = "\\dbn\SharedApp\OpenConnectors\OpenConnector\Config\$customer.xml"
$nsconfig = "\\dbn\SharedApp\OpenConnectors\OpenConnector\OpenConnectorPrograms\NetsuiteConfigs\$customer.xml"
$customer = @(Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases" | Out-GridView -Title 'Choose Database to be Migrated to VPC:' -PassThru)

write-host "The Customer is named $customer"
if (test-path $plugins) {write-host "Plugin library for $customer detected."} else {write-host "Plugin library for $customer does not exist"}
if (test-path $occonfig) {write-host "Open Connector configuration for $customer detected."} else {write-host "Open Connector configuration for $customer does not exist"}
if (test-path $nsconfig) {write-host "NetSuite configuration for $customer detected."} else {write-host "NetSuite configuration for $customer does not exist"}
```

Incorrect script output:

```
PS SQLSERVER:\> F:\ScriptRepo\MigratePortal.ps1
The Customer is named System.Data.DataRow
Plugin library for System.Data.DataRow does not exist
Open Connector configuration for System.Data.DataRow does not exist
NetSuite configuration for System.Data.DataRow does not exist
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow?view=net-5.0

So you've returned a row of data.  Keep in mind that the row could contain any number of columns.  In this case you need to define the column that you want to get the data from.  Something like
```$customer = @(Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases" | Out-GridView -Title 'Choose Database to be Migrated to VPC:' -PassThru).Item[name]```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the data from the database/out-gridview to `$customer` which is a parameter you have typed to `[string]` so the object is being saved with it's `ToString()` value which is `System.Data.DataRow`.  Change this variable to something different that is not already used like $database

Comment: I see what you are saying. I did as you suggested. I renamed the customer variable and also tried completely taking out the parameter declaration altogether and still got the same output. Now $database = System.Data.DataRow. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel answer is correct. You might of had a lingering variable assignment or lingering function definition, be sure you remove the function from memory when you are testing to be sure you are running what you think you are. FYI spacing in a file does not increase its size all that much as compared being able to read it.  Use line breaks and indentation to make it readable for your own sanity.

I ran the following:

```
[string]$customer = 'Fred'

$plugins = "\\dbn\SharedApp\WebServices\PacejetPreprocessWS\PluginLibraries\$customer\"
$occonfig = "\\dbn\SharedApp\OpenConnectors\OpenConnector\Config\$customer.xml"
$nsconfig = "\\dbn\SharedApp\OpenConnectors\OpenConnector\OpenConnectorPrograms\NetsuiteConfigs\$customer.xml"
$database = @(Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query 'SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases' | Out-GridView -Title 'Choose Database to be Migrated to VPC:' -PassThru)

Write-Host "The Customer is named $customer"
if (Test-Path $plugins) { 
    Write-Host "Plugin library for $customer detected." 
} else { 
    Write-Host "Plugin library for $customer does not exist" 
}

if (Test-Path $occonfig) { 
    Write-Host "Open Connector configuration for $customer detected." 
} else { 
    Write-Host "Open Connector configuration for $customer does not exist" 

}
if (Test-Path $nsconfig) { 
    Write-Host "NetSuite configuration for $customer detected." 
} else { 
    Write-Host "NetSuite configuration for $customer does not exist" 
}
```

and got:

```
The Customer is named Fred
Plugin library for Fred does not exist
Open Connector configuration for Fred does not exist
NetSuite configuration for Fred does not exist
```

You can shorten your output statements to something like:

```
"Plugin library for $customer $(if(Test-Path $plugins){'detected'}else{'does not exist'}
```